# What kind of encoding could it be?

Tags: symbols

`ΠλϠΓζλϠΓΡΔ ΩΡΔϠΔΠξηΠ ξΔϠΓϑΔζΓΩ μΔΞζλΓϑΔΓ ζηΓΠηφαλΠ ΓηΡΦΔΠξαΠ ηΓΡΔμΠαϑλ
ϠΓΔΠΓφλΠΦ ΡΔϠλΓΦΔΠΔ ΡηζΓφλΠϠξ αξμΛΔΠξΔΓ ΩλΡΓβλζμΠ ξηϑΓΛΓΔζΔ φφαλΠΓϑΔΓ
ζηϠΓΩΡλβα ΠφαηϠΓϗμΔ ΓζηΓφλΣΩλ ΠΔΠΓΔΠΓφμ ΣΩζαΣαΔΠξ λΓϑΔΓΩηφξ λϠΓΩΡΔΔΨα
ϠξΔΠξΔϠΓφ λΠΓΔζΓλΞΘ ΔξλΓϑΔΓφλ ΠϠξαξμαΡΓ ζηΓμΠαλΠΓ ΠηφαλΠηζΓ ηϨαηΠϖηΡΓ
ζηΓΘμϠξαφ αηΓφλΠϠλζ αϑηΡΓζηΓΩ ηϖΓαΠξΔΡα λΡΓΩΡλβΔΔ ΡΓηΓζηΓϑΔ ϨΔΠϠηΓφλΣ
μΠΓΩΡλΣλβ ΔΡΓΔζΓΞαΔ ΠΔϠξηΡΓΦΔ ΠΔΡηζΓΛΓη ϠΔΦμΡηΡΓζ λϠΓΞΔΠΔϨα φαλϠΓϑΔΓζ
ηΓζαΞΔΡξη ϑΓΩηΡηΓΠλ ϠλξΡλϠΓΩη ΡηΓΠμΔϠξΡ ηΓΩλϠξΔΡα ϑηϑΓΛΓΩηΡ ηΓξλϑλϠΓζ
λϠΓελΣΞΡΔ ϠΓϑΔζΓΣμΠ ϑλΓϗμΔΓϗμ αΔΡηΠΓεηΞ αξηΡΓΔΠΓΔ ζΓϠμΔζλΓη ΡΦΔΠξαΠλΓ
αΠβλφηΠϑλ ΓζηΓΩΡλξΔ φφαλΠΓϑΔΓ ϑαλϠΓϨμΔΠ ξΔΓϑΔΓξλϑ ηΓΡηϖλΠΓΛ ΓΘμϠξαφαη
ΓλΡϑΔΠηΣλ ϠΓϑΔφΡΔξη ΣλϠΓΛΓΔϠξ ηΞζΔφΔΣλϠ ΓΔϠξηΓφλΠ ϠξαξμφαλΠ ΓΩηΡηΓζηΓ
ΠηφαλΠΓηΡ ΦΔΠξαΠη`

First I thought I could somehow resolve it by the [greek numerals](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals). But then I realized it has not only greek symbols but one coptic symbol (`Ϩ`: [hori](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%A8)) which does not represent any number.

Seems tricky to me. What do you say?

Comment: welcome to Puzzling. Go ahead and take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about this site and get another badge. In order for us to help you with this puzzle, you will likely have to provide the full puzzle.

Comment: The Coptic alphabet is a variant of the Greek alphabet.

Comment: @micsthepick Do you have any reason to believe this cipher is connected to any language other than English (and Greek)?

Comment: Where'd you find this puzzle? The source will most likely help with answering

Comment: Well it might be connected to spanish. I mean the message is possibly in spanish. But I don't have any additional information about the answer.
I guess it is an issue for programmers.

Comment: There are 25 symbols used, so it may very well be a substitution cipher.

Comment: I take it, that you *don't* know the solution to this puzzle, correct?  In this case, it can be extremly helpful to know more about the puzzle origin & context. f.e. Has it been *formatted* exactly as posted? (As 11 rows of 7 columns of 9 characters each  (with 5 columns missing in the last row)? Have you received it digitally or printed out? etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't decipher the message, so I will just share some properties I found in the cyphertext and the conclusions I drew from them, in the hope that someone can think of something.

- The first and last blocks have a different number of characters. This could indicate that the spaces were added at fixed positions after the message was encrypted, and that the blocks are not intended to be treated as units. (But why would the first block have an extra character then?
- There are different 25 Greek-alphabet symbols, some in uppercase and some in lowercase. This is the approximately the number of letters in a alphabet of a typical Latin-script language.
- The letters used include some little known Greek letters, including one from the Coptic variant, and fail to use certain common letters.

  - What do most of common the missing letters have in common? They are similar to their Latin counterparts (i.e., Ε, Α, Κ, ο etc. are not used). I think this points towards an attempt to hide Latin-script text.
- The frequency distribution is **what you expect from a simple substitution cipher** (see sections below).
- There are only 2 letters that occur in a row: φφ and ΔΔ (two times each). If this is a simple substitution cipher, the language is probably one that doesn't use repeated letters often (thus we can exclude English, French and German).
- Most occurrences of ϑ are followed by Δ
- Most occurrences of Ϡ are followed by Γ or ξ
- Most occurrences of Ω are followed by η or Ρ
- Most occurrences of λ are followed by Π or Ϡ
- 4 out of 6 occurences of Λ are "ΓΛΓ"
- 3 out of 3 occurences of ϗ are "Γϗμ"
- the long sequence "ΓζηΓΠηφαλΠΓηΡΦΔΠξαΠη" occurs twice.

I tried to match the text with Spanish based on the assumption that "φαλΠ" (6 occurrences) corresponds to the common suffix *-ción*. But that led me nowhere.

**Frequencies**:

- **1 letter:** Γ 99, Δ 69, η 58, λ 56, Π 54, Ρ 39, α 37, Ϡ 36, ξ 34, ζ 29, φ 25, ϑ 23, μ 19, Ω 17, Σ 10, Ξ 8, Φ 7, Λ 6, β 5, Ϩ 4, Θ 3, ϖ 3, ϗ 3, ε 2, Ψ 1
- **2 letter (5 or more occurrences):** ηΓ 21, ϠΓ 18, ΔΠ 18, λϠ 15, λΠ 15, ΠΓ 14, ΓΩ 14, Γζ 14, ϑΔ 12, ηΡ 12, Γϑ 12, Ϡξ 11, Πξ 11, ΔΓ 11, φα 10, Ρη 10, ΡΓ 10, ζη 10, αλ 10, ΔϠ 9, Γφ 9, ΓΔ 9, φλ 8, ξη 8, ξΔ 8, ξα 8, λΓ 8, ζΓ 8, ΔΡ 8, ΡΔ 7, Πη 7, Δζ 7, ΩΡ 6, Ωη 6, μΔ 6, Γη 6, αΠ 6, ΦΔ 5, Ρλ 5, ΠϠ 5, ΠΔ 5, ξλ 5, μΠ 5, ΛΓ 5, ζλ 5, ΓΠ 5, ΓΛ 5
- **3 letters (4 or more occurrences):** λϠΓ 13, ΓϑΔ 11, Γζη 10, ζηΓ 9, Γφλ 8, ΔΠξ 8, λΠΓ 8, αλΠ 7, φαλ 7, ϑΔΓ 7, ΓΩη 6, φλΠ 6, ΓΛΓ 5, ΓΩΡ 5, ΔζΓ 5, ΠξΔ 5, ΡηΓ 5, ΦΔΠ 5, ηΡΓ 5, Ϡξα 5, ΓΔζ 4, ΔΓζ 4, ΔΠΓ 4, ΔΠΔ 4, ΔϠξ 4, ΡΓζ 4, ΩΡλ 4, ΩηΡ 4, ηΓΠ 4, ηΓφ 4, ηΡη 4, λΠϠ 4, ϠΓϑ 4
- **4 letters (3 or more occurrences):** ΓζηΓ  9, ΓϑΔΓ  7, ΓφλΠ  6, αλΠΓ  6, φαλΠ  6, ΓΩΡλ  4, ΓΩηΡ  4, ΔΓζη  4, ΩηΡη  4, ηΓφλ  4, ηΡηΓ  4, φλΠϠ  4, ϠΓϑΔ  4, ΓΔΠΓ  3, ΓΔζΓ  3, ΓΠηφ  3, ΓζλϠ  3, ΓηΡΦ  3, ΔΠξΔ  3, ΔΠξα  3, ΔϠξη  3, Πηφα  3, ΠξαΠ  3, ΠϠξα  3, ΡΓζη  3, ΡΦΔΠ  3, ΣλϠΓ  3, ΦΔΠξ  3, ζλϠΓ  3, ηΡΓζ  3, ηΡΦΔ  3, ηφαλ  3, λΓϑΔ  3, λΠϠξ  3, ξαξμ  3, ϑΔΓζ  3, Ϡξαξ  3
- **5 letters (3 or more occurrences):** φαλΠΓ 5, ΓΩηΡη 4, ΓφλΠϠ 4, ΩηΡηΓ 4, ΓΠηφα 3, ΓζλϠΓ 3, ΓηΡΦΔ 3, ΓϑΔΓζ 3, ΔΓζηΓ 3, ΔΠξαΠ 3, Πηφαλ 3, ΠϠξαξ 3, ΡΓζηΓ 3, ΡΦΔΠξ 3, ΦΔΠξα 3, ηΡΦΔΠ 3, ηφαλΠ 3, λΓϑΔΓ 3, λΠϠξα 3, φλΠϠξ 3, ϑΔΓζη 3, Ϡξαξμ 3
- **6 letters (2 or more occurrences):**  ΓΩηΡηΓ 4, ΓΠηφαλ 3, ΓηΡΦΔΠ 3, ΓφλΠϠξ 3, ΓϑΔΓζη 3, ΠηφαλΠ 3, ΠϠξαξμ 3, ΡΦΔΠξα 3, ΦΔΠξαΠ 3, ηΡΦΔΠξ 3, λΠϠξαξ 3, φλΠϠξα 3, ΓΘμϠξα 2, ΓΦΔΠΔΡ 2, ΓζηΓΠη 2, ΔΠΔΡηζ 2, ΔΠξαΠη 2, ΔφφαλΠ 2, ΔϠΓϑΔζ 2, ΘμϠξαφ 2, ΠΓηΡΦΔ 2, ΠΔΡηζΓ 2, ΦΔΠΔΡη 2, ΩηΡηΓΠ 2, αλΠΓηΡ 2, αλΠΓϑΔ 2, ζηΓΠηφ 2, ηΓΠηφα 2, ηΓφλΠϠ 2, ηΡΓζηΓ 2, ηφαλΠΓ 2, λΠΓηΡΦ 2, λΠΓϑΔΓ 2, λϠΓζλϠ 2, μϠξαφα 2, ξαφαηΓ 2, ξλΓϑΔΓ 2, φαλΠΓη 2, φαλΠΓϑ 2, φφαλΠΓ 2, ϑΔΓζηΓ 2, ϠΓζλϠΓ 2, ϠΓϑΔζΓ 2, Ϡξαφαη 2
- **7 letter (2 or more occurrences):**  ΓΠηφαλΠ 3, ΓηΡΦΔΠξ 3, ΓφλΠϠξα 3, ΡΦΔΠξαΠ 3, ηΡΦΔΠξα 3, λΠϠξαξμ 3, φλΠϠξαξ 3, ΓΘμϠξαφ 2, ΓΦΔΠΔΡη 2, ΓΩηΡηΓΠ 2, ΓζηΓΠηφ 2, ΓϑΔΓζηΓ 2, ΔΠΔΡηζΓ 2, ΔφφαλΠΓ 2, ΔϠΓϑΔζΓ 2, ΘμϠξαφα 2, ΠΓηΡΦΔΠ 2, ΠηφαλΠΓ 2, ΦΔΠΔΡηζ 2, ΦΔΠξαΠη 2, αλΠΓηΡΦ 2, αλΠΓϑΔΓ 2, ζηΓΠηφα 2, ηΓΠηφαλ 2, ηφαλΠΓη 2, λΠΓηΡΦΔ 2, λϠΓζλϠΓ 2, μϠξαφαη 2, φαλΠΓηΡ 2, φαλΠΓϑΔ 2, φφαλΠΓϑ 2, ϠξαφαηΓ 2

Any ideas?